# specify country code in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the regex I'm currently using to validate user phone input. Is it possible to alter it to work for a specific country-code like the testPhoneNumber in the code below. (+264)

```js
var testPhoneNumber = '(+264)814696144';
var testPattern =/^\(?(\+[0-9]{3})\)?[-.]?([0-9]{2})?[-.]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Comment: But it seems working, just add `alert(testPattern.test(testPhoneNumber));`. The result is `true`.

Comment: "_Is it possible to alter it to work ..._" Yes, of course. Can you show what you tried and explain what isn't working?

Comment: If you mean you only want to accept the 264 code, replace the first `\+[0-9]{3}` with the literal `\+264`. Btw, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Comment: @m69 Thanks exactly what I was looking for. Oh cool thanks \d is faster ;-).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is: "This RegEx validates my `testPhoneNumber`, but I *only* want it to validate against +264 area codes, not **every** area code."

In that case, then

```
var testPattern =/^\(?(\+(?:264))\)?[-.]?([0-9]{2})?[-.]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/;

// testPattern.test('(+264)814696144');
// returns true
// testPattern.test('(+265)814696144');
// returns false
```

would work.

Note, if you want to add more area codes individually (like 456, and 789) you can place them in the `(?:)` section like so:

```
var testPattern =/^\(?(\+(?:264|456|789))\)?[-.]?([0-9]{2})?[-.]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Just separate them by a pipe `|`, which acts as an `or` in regular expressions.